# How to access object in viewModel from outside activity or fragment class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I have a app in which I'm trying go implement the MVVM pattern for the first time.
I have a simple fragment with the corresponding viewModel and a seperate class that deals with the swipeToDelete from the recyclerView which is in the fragment.

The viewModel looks like this:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class ListViewModel : ViewModel() {

var keedList: ArrayList<Keed> = ArrayList()
}
```

And the SwipeToDelete class like this:

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class SwipeToDelete : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

// since the feature is not used, simply return "false"
override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder) = false

override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
    val position: Int = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    keedList.removeAt(position)              // this is not working, "keedList" is red.
    viewModel.keedList.removeAt(position)    // this is not working either... "viewModel" is red.
    myAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }
}
```

the other files should be irrelevant I guess.

Now the problem ist, that I can't remove my swiped off item in the "onSwiped" function since it won't recognize my "keedList" or the "viewModel" in the function because the SwipeToDelete class is neighter fragment or activity (I tried both cases...).

Is there a general flaw on how I'm designing it? How could that be solved?

Thanks for your help.

And here is my code in the fragment before using on of the two approaches:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_list.*
import marcelfuchs.example.org.keed.databinding.FragmentListBinding

lateinit var myAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

class MainListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: ListViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        myAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(viewModel.keedList)
        rv_killsDeaths.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity())
        rv_killsDeaths.adapter = myAdapter

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_enterItemsFragment)
        }

        // close the softKeyboard as it keeps on opening when returning from NewItemFragment
        val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(requireView().windowToken, 0)

        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(SwipeToDelete())
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_killsDeaths)

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    //Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any references to the binding class instance in the fragment's onDestroyView() method.
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a listener to the SwipeToDelete class and invoke it whenever an item in the `RecyclerView` is swiped.

```kotlin
class SwipeToDelete(private val deletionListener: (Int) -> Unit) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) = false

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val position: Int = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        deletionListener.invoke(position)   
    }
}
```

In your fragment, you can remove that item from your list

```kotlin
val swipeToDeleteCallback = SwipeToDelete { position ->
    viewModel.keedList.removeAt(position)
    myAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback)
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_killsDeaths)
```

Or, you could create an object within the fragment instead of a separate class (Makes sense if it is not being reused in other fragments/activities). Like so:

```kotlin
val swipeToDeleteCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) = false

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val position: Int = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        viewModel.keedList.removeAt(position)
        myAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)   
    }
}

val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback)
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_killsDeaths)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I'm back home. Would it make sense by the way to put the SwipeToDelete class in the fragment class, or leave it as a class (file) of its own?

Comment: Have updated the answer. It would make sense to create an object in the fragment (without creating a separate class) if it is not being reused anywhere else. If the swipe to delete functionality is required by other `RecyclerView` objects in your application then you should keep it as a separate class (file) and follow the approach I have suggested.

Comment: When I'm using the 1. approach, I have 2 problems:  Since I created a constructor in the SwipeToDelet class, I now have to pass a value to my SwipeToDelete() call that I have in my fragment. What do I have to pass in as a deletionListener? And the second question, the swipeToDeleteHelper variable is never used when I put that into the fragment, where would I put that anyway, in the onCreateView or in the onViewCreated?

Comment: For the 2.approach (which I would prefer, since I don't use it anywhere else) it is the same thing, when I put it in the fragment, the swipeToDeleteHelper remains grey, stating that it's nowhere used. Sorry, those are probably very silly questions, but I'm very new to this. I'll try to post my fragment code, if I can manage....

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to replace your code `val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(SwipeToDelete())` with the code examples i have provided

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Like a charm. Although I have to read into what the code is exactly doing. Thank you very much for your quick help, very much appreciated :-)